Parameters undefined after passing to composables in Vue 3
I have input field and a button on my page, input field bound to 'artistName' variable and button bound to callApi function. I want to pass an argument to a function in a composable in Vue 3 but whatever I tried always returns undefined. How can I approach this? Thank you
HomeView.vue;
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';
import fetchArtist from '../composables/fetchArtist';

const artistName = ref('');
const clicked = ref(false);

const updateText = (event) => {
    artistName.value = event.target.value;
};

const {dataList, sendRequest} = fetchArtist();

const callApi = () => {
    sendRequest(artistName.value);
    clicked.value = true;
};  
</script>

fetchArtist.js (composoble file);
import { ref } from 'vue';

export default function sendRequest(artistName) {
    const dataList = ref([]);

    try {
        fetch(`APIURL/{artistName}`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.artists && data.artists.length > 0) {
                dataList.value = data.artists.map(artist => ({
                    id: artist.id,
                    name: artist.name,
                    country: artist.country ? artist.country : 'Unknown'
                }));
            }
        })

    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    }

    return { dataList, sendRequest };
}


I tried make the composable function async and receive with await in the HomeView.vue but that didn't work too.

does event.target.value has value? why aren't not using v-model?

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. There's no context for these snippets. "I tried make the composable function async" - what did you try? That sendRequest returns itself is a potential mistake, it's unknown how this affects the case
